The term 'ts-node' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program
ts_node : The term 'ts_node' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the 
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ ts_node
+ ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (ts_node:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

I tried all solutions mentioned here in Stack Overflow and some others but could not help me. Still giving me same error. I paste in whole error message here above. I installed ts-node locally and globally using these commands:
# Locally in your project.
npm install -D typescript
npm install -D ts-node

# Or globally with TypeScript.
npm install -g typescript
npm install -g ts-node

I am using Node.js 18 and Windows 11, npm version 10.1.0, TypeScript: 5.2.2 but it's not working for me.

I am working with it from last many months, it's work well but suddenly got this error first time.

After working hard and search finally I got it's working. I used npx at start of command and worked for me.
npx ts-node-esm src/app.ts

Oddly, I ran into this same issue after a windows 11 update. Prior to the update I was able to successfully run ts-node src/app.ts, but after the update I got the error that ts-node was not recognized. There are several ways to fix the problem.

Add %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\npm to the PATH environment variable in Windows.  Or for a temporary PATH fix, from the command line run
$env:Path += ";$env:USERPROFILE\AppData\Roaming\npm"

Prefix the command with npx and run
npx ts-node src/app.ts

Add the command to package.json file like so:
  "scripts": {
     "start": "ts-node src/app.ts",
   }



then to run simply use
npm start
